# Can a two-dimensional array in C be initialized without explicit size?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, initialization

I have a question regarding two-dimensional arrays in C. I know now (from direct compiler experience) that I can't initialize such an array analogously to one-dimensional arrays like this:

```
int multi_array[][] = {
  {1,2,3,4,5},
  {10,20,30,40,50},
  {100,200,300,400,500}
};

> compiler output:

gcc -o arrays arrays.c
arrays.c: In function ‘main’:
arrays.c:8:9: error: array type has incomplete element type
```

The closest solution that works is to provide the number of columns explicitly like this:

```
int multi_array[][5] = {
  {1,2,3,4,5},
  {10,20,30,40,50},
  {100,200,300,400,500}
};
```

My question is: can it be done neatly *without* supplying the number explicitly (which after all the compiler should be able to infer itself)? I'm not talking about manually constructing it with `malloc` or something but rather something close to what I tried.
Also, can someone knowledgeable about C compilers explain from a low-level perspective why my initial attempt does not work?

I used plain `gcc` with no non-standard options to compile the code.

Thanks

Comment: How are you going to declare a function that uses `multi_array` as one of its parameters?

Comment: in the first case the compiler can infer both dimension of `multi_array`, but in this case if the programmer provide different sizes it will gave an error like "mismatching array size on initialization"... I guess the designer preferred that the programmer states what size he expects and then check against that size.

Comment: *"Also, can someone knowledgeable about C compilers explain from a low-level perspective why my initial attempt does not work?"* - Because the specification requires explicit sizes for all dimensions after one.  Now, *why* that is the case I can't say I know.

Comment: @clcto: It can be inferred by the initialization. That is the bit which is confusing, not the fact that the dimensions need to be defined in general.

Comment: When C was designed, computers with 16KB RAM were common -- C was at least largely built on one with 8KB -- so it's easy to see why it wasn't in the language at first.  Why it's not in the language now?  Nobody ever cared enough to change the language when any programmers' editor can count commas for you, would be my guess.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to those questions in the original post, I just want to point out that what the asker propose may be not such a good or useful idea.

---

The compiler indeed can infer from

```
int multi_array[][] = {
  {1,2,3,4,5},
  {10,20,30,40,50},
  {100,200,300,400,500}
};
```

the structure of `multi_array`.

But when you want to declare and define a function (this declaration and definition could be in another compilation unit or source file) that supposes to accept `multi_array` as one of its argument, you still need to do something like

```
int foo(..., int multi_array[][COL], ...) { }
```

Compiler needs this `COL` to do proper pointer arithmetic in `foo()`.

Usually, we define `COL` as a macro that will be replaced by an integer in a header file, and use it in the definitions of `multi_array` and `foo()`:

```
int multi_array[][COL] = { ... };

int foo(..., int multi_array[][COL], ...) { }
```

By doing this, it is easy to make sure they are the same. And let compiler to infer the structure of `multi_array` according to its initialization, when you give it a wrong initialization, you actually introduce a bug in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the C99 compound literal feature.

A partial idea is that the length of an initializer list can be determined like this:

```
sizeof (int[]){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } / sizeof(int)
```

We need a workaround for the fact that the only way you can pass an argument containing a comma to a macro is to put parentheses around (part of) the argument:

```
#define ROW(...) { __VA_ARGS__ }
```

Then the following macro deduces the second dimension from the first row:

```
#define MAGIC_2DARRAY(type, ident, row1, ...) \
        type ident[][sizeof (type[])row1 / sizeof (type)] = { \
                row1, __VA_ARGS__ \
        }
```

It only works if there are at least two rows.

Example:

```
MAGIC_2DARRAY(int, arr, ROW(7, 8, 9), ROW(4, 5, 6));
```

You probably do not want to use this in a real program, but it is possible.

For passing this kind of array to functions, the C99 variable length array feature is useful, with a function like:

```
void printarr(int rows, int columns, int array[rows][columns]) { ... }
```

called as:

```
printarr(sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0], sizeof arr[0] / sizeof arr[0][0], arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

2D arrays in `C` are stored in contiguous memory locations. So if you do not provide the number of rows or the number of columns, how will the compiler know how many rows and column there are?

For a [row major matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), rows contents are at contiguous memory positions. So you need to specify at least the number of columns. Similarly for a column major matrix, you need to specify at least the number of rows. Whether it is row major or column major is defined by architecture. It seems that what you have is a row major architecture.

Comment: Yep, but in the asker's case he is providing the initializers, and from that the compiler could infere the size of the first dimension has the asker has remarked in his question.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do it. If you even don't initialize, you can't define an int array[][];

Answer (score -1):

Create a structure with 1d arrays. However, if you follow this method you can create new arrays but it will be a function call to change sizes and values. A dynamic matrix approach could come close to solving your issue.

Comment: It will be better to address the OP issue. He stated in the question he doesn't want to hear about dynamic allocation.